# To render a button based on a apex:inputcheckbox field - having console error

Tags: visualforce

Aim: To achieve when a checkbox is selected button should show else hide.

[image]

```
<td><apex:inputCheckbox id="checkBoxId" value="{!a.selected}"
                                onclick="
    if(this.checked){                                          
   document.getElementById({!$Component.displayButton}).style.display='block';
   }
   else
   {                                       
    document.getElementById({!$Component.displayButton}).style.display='none';}"/>
   </td>
<apex:outputPanel id="displySelectedAccs">
   <apex:commandButton id= "displayButton" value ="getSelectedItems" action="{!getSelectedItems}"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

In browser console, I see an error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing )

after argument list.

I have tired Jquery hide()/show() listed in below link

[To render a button based on a apex:inputcheckbox field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/107342/to-render-a-button-based-on-a-apexinputcheckbox-field)

I am stuck. any inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox id="checkBoxId" value="{!a.selected}"
                            onclick="toggleDisplay();"/>
<script type="text\javascript">
function toggledDisplay(){
     var checked = $j("[id*=checkBoxId]").is(':checked');
     if (checked){
         //I usually use jQuery show/hide
     else {

     }
}
</script>
```

Comment: could you provide an explanation rather than just dumping code? thanks

Comment: @Charlie123 Thanks, It worked! 1) but the requirement is changed. button should be grayed out instead of hide any inputs?I was able to hide. 2) but I am still not be able to understand document.getElementById(..) did not work.

Comment: 1) you want to change the color of the button? Or disable it? I think some HTML objects have a "disabled" attribute, you might want to look into that 2. Visualforce adds a bunch of characters to the beginning of IDs in the actual HTML it generates. That's why document.getElementByID() wasn't working for you. The * in the [id*=...] jQuery selector is a wildcard, basically selecting an element with the id that ends with "checkBoxId."